# Android (AndEngine): How to obtain touch input events outside onSceneTouchEvent method?

Tags: android, input, touch, andengine

So, here's my problem: in my game I made a countdown at the start of the game, during which the user can't press the screen, so I wait until the countdown is over to enable the OnSceneTouchListener. As soon as it's enabled, the user will be able to do some stuff moving the finger (not important what).

The problem is that if the user starts moving the finger while there's the countdown, as soon as it's over the onSceneTouchEvent method starts getting inputs, but it skips the ACTION_DOWN event since the user is already moving the finger.

To prevent this I could of course use a boolean inside the onSceneTouchEvent method, but this way it would always check that for every single input. It doesn't influence much the performance, but I'd rather find another way if it's possible.

So I was thinking, is there a way in the AndEngine to obtain the touch input event (with the information of the coordinate pressed, that's what I really need), so that I could "force" the ACTION_DOWN event by simple doing what I should do with it in the method that makes the countdown?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how you can get touch coordinates.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int myEventAction = event.getAction(); 

    float X = event.getX();
float Y = event.getY();

    switch (myEventAction) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            mySprite.setPosition(X, Y);
            break;}
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Source of this example](http://andengineguides.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/getting-started-touch-events/)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but I'll try to be more clear... I already use a method like that, which costantly check for inputs; what I need is to be able to access to touch input OUTSIDE this method, so that I can check only ONCE the input; if I implement a check in the onTouchEvent method, it will ALWAYS execute it, but I want it to do the check only once. I don't know if I explained it right...